# Trigger a button automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to perform some manipulations and submit a web form application (C#) automatically (for example once a day). In this example, everyday new requirement in a form must be selected based on the day and must be submitted itself.

Comment: why not execute the button click handler once a day?!

Comment: Isn't it the job of a scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

you need a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

you can set the intervall in milliseconds

aspx:

```
 <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="10000" />
```

cs:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do stuff here
}
```